# Create JIRA ticket under kanban board via REST API

Tags: jira, rest, kanban

Create JIRA ticket under kanban board via REST API

Can we create JIRA ticket under Kanban board through REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an issue via Rest API. The board will be base on Project or Filter. So you can just create an issue in the proper project or the filter can see it, it will appear in the board.

Here is the rest api to create an issue: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-post